# UINavigationController is Automatically popping to root view when device rotates

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, orientation

I currently have multiple views open as children to my navigation controller through the method navigation controller.push(). When you rotate the device it automatically goes back all the way to the root view controller, as if you called poptorootview().

I am wondering why it is doing this and how to stop this from happening. I have not modified UINavigationController class in any way.

Thank you!

Comment: this problem is killing me , please tell me if you found the solution

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else is looking for any workaround .I had this really annoying issue in iOS 11.1 only but everything was looking good in iOS 10 and below.
Finally I got it fixed by updating my Xcode to 9.2 and the problem has been disappeard, still I have no idea what caused that, but it take 3 days to me to get rid of it!